# Why doesn't 'ActionsChains' methods work for me in Selenium for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a simple python program to enter a search key and then open that link in new tab using "i am feeling lucky"  from google using selenium.

The problem is the `context_click()` method doesn't do anything. it doesn't even show any errors. The `click()` method from ActionsChains also doesn't work(no errors but no effect). but the simple `webelement.click()` does work.
Code:

```
import  selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
opts = Options()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver")
opts.add_argument('--headless')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
act = ActionChains(driver)
driver.find_element_by_id('lst-ib').send_keys("some_search_word_that_doesnt_have_suggestions")
webelem=driver.find_element_by_name('btnI')
act.context_click(webelem)
```

Also i have been trying to run this in headless mode using opts.add_argument('--headless') but even that doesn't work at all(no errors but window still pop ups).(A quick fix to this is appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following line to the end of your code.

```
act.perform()
```

From the docs https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

> When you call perform(), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

Note your code opens the context menu (right click), if you actually want to click the button use:

```
act.click(webelem)
```